# Javascript in js.erb file not being executed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a remote request using ruby on rails.
The request hits a `create` action endpoint, which then uses a `create.js.erb` file to execute some javascript on the page.

However, the javascript is not being executed.
I know that i'm definitely entering the `.js.erb` file because i can hit it using a `raise`. However no js, is being run (i have tested by adding a `debugger` and also just a `console.log` and neither are being hit).

I'm thinking this might be because of how i've set up the request?

The controller looks like this

```
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js do
            render layout: false
          end
        end
```

The request looks like:

```
            headers: { "Content-Type" => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            method: "post",
            type: "request",
            url: car_path(car_id: 18, filters: { types: types }, format: :js),
```

I have also changed the headers to `application/json` which also has not worked.

Is there a flag or something that i'm missing?

Comment: What you need to do here is diagnose the problem from the browser side. Open up the inspector in the browser and look at the network tab. If Rails UJS / jquery ujs is working properly you should  see an xhr request with a `application/javascript` accept type.